# Print actual string found

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have this code which checks if a word from the list "Markers" can be found in the string "Translation".

```
Translation= words.split("Translation:",1)[1]
if any(x in Translation for x in Markers):
    print "found"
```

How do i print the actual string that is found. I tried doing this

```
Translation= words.split("Translation:",1)[1]
if any(x in Translation for x in Markers):
    print x
```

But i kept getting an error. New to Python. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *But i kept getting an error* which one?

Comment: `any()` returns True or False, the `x` you use in the any call only exists in the scope of `any(..)`. You cannot refer to it outside the any call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get that with `any` function, as it returns a boolean. So you need to use a `for` loop like this

```
for item in markers:
    if item in translation:
        print item
        break
else:
    print "Not Found"
```

If you want to get all the matching elements then you can use a list comprehension, like this

```
print [item for item in markers if item in translation]
```

As [Martijn suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803384/print-actual-string-found/23803468?noredirect=1#comment36614727_23803468), we can simply get the first match with

```
print next((x for x in markers if x in translation), None)
```

If there is no match, then it will return `None`.

Note that, [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests us to not to name our local variables with initial capital letters. So, I named with lowercase letters.

Comment: What about `[print x for x in markers if x in translation]`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns We cannot have any statements inside LC.

Comment: What about `next((x for x in markers if x in translation), None)` to get just the first match?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup, forgot about that. Thanks :) Included that also in the answer.